# Jquery Help to get .attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I wanted to ask. Why `.attr("title")` don't work? 
In title goes date of calendar like: "2011712", and I need to substring it.. But when I do this nothing happening?

EDIT: the tap event is working fine.. but i dont get "Title" in header text..

Tap event->

```
            $('.div-cell').tap(function() {
                            var i;
                              for (i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
                                $('#' + i + 'dayCell').removeClass('tapped');
                                      }

                              $(this).toggleClass(
                                   'tapped');

                                var myDate2 = $(this).attr("title").substring(5,7) +" "+ months[$(this).attr("title").substring(4,5)];


                              $('#MSchedule header h4').text("Schedule  -  " + myDate2);
                    });
```

Calendar creation ->

```
function setCalendar() {

    var cTime = new Date();
    var myDate = months[cTime.getMonth()] + " " + cTime.getFullYear();
    var myDate2 = cTime.getDate() + " " + months[cTime.getMonth()];


    $('#MCalendar header h4').text(myDate);
     $('#MSchedule header h4').text("Schedule  -  " + myDate2)

    var monthView = new Array(42);

    var firstDayOfMonth = new Date(cTime.getFullYear(), cTime.getMonth(), 1);

    while (firstDayOfMonth.getDay() != 1) {

        firstDayOfMonth.addDays(-1);

    }

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < monthView.length; i++) {
        startDate = new Date(firstDayOfMonth);

        monthView[i] = startDate.addDays(i);

    }

    var day = 0;
    $("#calendar")
            .children()
            .each(
                    function() {
                        var row = $(this);

                        if ($(this).hasClass('weekdays')) {

                        } else {
                            row
                                    .children()
                                    .each(
                                            function() {

                                                var cell = $(this);
                                                var content = '<div class="dayNumberCellValue" title="' + monthView[day].getYear()+
                                                monthView[day].getMonth()+monthView[day].getDate()+ '">'
                                                        + monthView[day]
                                                                .getDate()
                                                        + '</div>';
                                                cell.append(content);

                                                if (monthView[day]
                                                        .getMonth() != Date
                                                        .today().getMonth()) {
                                                    $(this).addClass(
                                                            'otherMonth');
                                                } else {

                                                    if (Date
                                                            .today()
                                                            .equals(
                                                                    monthView[day])) {
                                                        $(this).addClass(
                                                                'today');
                                                    }
                                                    $(this).addClass(
                                                            'noRecords');
                                                }

                                                day++;
                                            });
                        }

                    });
    $(".div-cell:contains('16')").removeClass('noRecords').addClass(
            'hasRecords');
    $(".div-cell:contains('17')").removeClass('noRecords').addClass(
            'hasRecords');
    $(".div-cell:contains('18')").removeClass('noRecords').addClass(
            'hasRecords');

    $(".div-cell:contains('20')").removeClass('noRecords').addClass(
            'onVacation');
    $(".div-cell:contains('21')").removeClass('noRecords').addClass(
            'onVacation');
    $(".div-cell:contains('22')").removeClass('noRecords').addClass(
            'onVacation');
}
```

EDIT:
HTML ->

```
<div id="calendar">
                        <div class="div-row weekdays">
                            <div class="div-cell-weekdays"></div>
                            <div class="div-cell-weekdays"></div>
                            <div class="div-cell-weekdays"></div>
                            <div class="div-cell-weekdays"></div>
                            <div class="div-cell-weekdays"></div>
                            <div class="div-cell-weekdays"></div>
                            <div class="div-cell-weekdays"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="div-row">
                            <div id="0dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="1dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="2dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="3dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="4dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="5dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="6dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="div-row">
                            <div id="7dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="8dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="9dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="10dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="11dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="12dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="13dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="div-row">
                            <div id="14dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="15dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="16dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="17dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="18dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="19dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="20dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="div-row">
                            <div id="21dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="22dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="23dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="24dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="25dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="26dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="27dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="div-row">
                            <div id="28dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="29dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="30dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="31dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="32dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="33dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="34dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="div-row">
                            <div id="35dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="36dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="37dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="38dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="39dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="40dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                            <div id="41dayCell" class="div-cell"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Need to see what the HTML looks like

Comment: So what exactly is not working? `myDate2` contains wrong (or empty) value, or `#MSchedule header h4` contents are not being changed?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question... perhaphs you should write it more clearly. Could you provide a fiddle also? That would help.

Comment: Please provide full code or link to jsfiddle as there are undefined variables in your code like array "months".

Comment: lxa - header text is changing when you tap.. but "title" are not shown..

Comment: algiecas - i can't provide the full code..months is a string array list of months names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error: I changed `"title"` to `"id"`.

My mistake was that in the tap function, I was calling another div that didn't contain the `"id"` tag.

```
                    $('.div-cell').tap(function() {
                            var i;
                            var myDate2;
                              for (i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
                                $('#' + i +'dayCell').removeClass('tapped');

                                      }

                              $(this).toggleClass(
                                   'tapped');
```

**> `var myDate2 = $('.dayNumberCellValue').attr('id');`**

```
                                    $('#MSchedule header h4').text("S - "+myDate2);
                                }
                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you have a semicolon `;` after your `attr("title").substring(5,7)`?

Comment: Sorry, no.. I just forgot to put it away.. :)   EDIT: i made it - var myDate2 = $(this).attr("title"); now but nothing happen too

Answer (score 0):

Title in the header is not an attribute.  right now you are telling it change this.

```
<div class="div-cell" title="what you are changing is going here"></div>
```

If you are actually trying to change the header title you need to do this.

```
document.title = 'blah';
```

Also lxa is right, you have a semicolon in your code where it shouldn't be.

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't understood what i meant.. I meant "title" don't go to header's text..